# Why isn't my main Window Showing up in This GUI which i haven't even stated in PyQt4 Python

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtgui

I was going to write a PyQt application when i was setting the main screen up i realize while running that my main window is not showing up and i also have a warning saying parameters flag unfilled in PyCharm

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
app = QtGui.Application(sys.argv)
main_window = QtGui.QWidget() # this where i am getting a warning 
main_window.show()
```

Comment: Pycharm has problems with the identification of some functions and classes of PyQt4, but that is only a warning, it is not an error.

Comment: yah but there is no window showing up wasn't there supposed to be a window showing up since main_window is created and i called the .show() object on the main window?

Comment: It appears but if there is no mainloop your window will be closed automatically, add `sys.exit(app.exec_())`, :P

Comment: lol yah true and the funny thing is that i thought about it and i wrote this code

Comment: while true: and then inside this i wrote main_window.show()

Comment: No, use: `import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
app = QtGui.Application(sys.argv)
main_window = QtGui.QWidget()
main_window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())`

Comment: app.exec_ () creates the mainloop

Comment: yah i got that but when i didnt kwew that i did line 3 which was funny